# Table tbody rendring very slow in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am facing issue with loading more time to render Table tbody response data on the screen in IE11 .where as in FF its loading quickly .

I am using below to append the data to tbody

```
doAppend(newPages)
{
  for(var i=0, iLen=newPages.length; i < iLen; i++)
      { 
           var page = newPages[i].pageNum; 
           this._table.append(paginatorTpl.NewTableBody({page: page})); 
           $('tbody[data-page=' + page + ']', this._table).html(newPages[i].rows);  
      }
}
```

Comment: can you please help on this

Comment: how many rows in tbody, i meet simaily issue too on IE while there are too many cells.

Comment: I am not sure because its completely based on response data

Comment: plz let me know how did you resolve this issue.

Comment: i did not resolve it yet, only happens while too many cells in table, and i will do manually resize cells' with and height

Comment: I will check ok Thanks.